# Check length of (x:xs)

Tags: haskell

I have a function something like this

```
checkSomething (x:xs) counter
| (length of x:xs)         = ...
| ...                      = ...
```

I want to check if the list (x:xs) is empty. I somehow didnt manage to do it with the (x:xs) notation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x:xs` is never empty: it always has element `x`. The canonical pattern for matching empty lists is `[]` (though it may be spelled `""` if it specifically has type `[Char]`). So, instead, you might write

```
checkSomething [] counter = {- the empty case -}
checkSomething (x:xs) counter = {- lists with at least one element -}
```