# Haskell - Check lenght of (x:xs) and apply function

Tags: haskell

I have a function qpFunc that takes two strings. s:os and p:ps. I call this function recursivley and traverese thourgh a list. When s:os is empty, I want to call a new function itWilcard (p:ps). However, when trying to put it as a pattern-match, it complains that

> "Variable not in scope: ps :: [Char]".

When used inside the function call it never reaches the condition it seems like since i get

> "Non-exhaustive patterns in function qpFunc"

when calling it with "" "?".

How can I check if the lists used as arguments are empty and if so, apply a new function?
In the question posted here [question stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599757/check-length-of-xxs) it says that

> "x:xs is never empty: it always has element x. The canonical pattern
> for matching empty lists is []"

However, in my case I want to apply a function if the pattern is met.

This is my code so far:

```
qpFunc :: String -> String -> (String, String)
qpFunc [] [] = ("", "")
qpFunc [] _ = itWilcard (p : ps) -- does not work
qpFunc (s : os) (p : ps)
  | (s : os) == [] = itWilcard (p : ps) -- never reached ?
  | p == '*' = (os, p : ps)
  | p == '?' = qpFunc os ps
  | s == p = (os, ps)
  | otherwise = ([], "#")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(s : os) == []` can never be true, because it's by construction a list that has `s` as its head (i.e., has at least this one element, and therefore isn't empty).

`qpFunc [] _ = itWilcard (p : ps)` can't work, because, well, what are `p` and `ps`? This clause can't know that in *another* clause, you match `p : ps`. But nothing stops you from doing it in this clause too:

```
qpFunc [] [] = ("", "")
qpFunc [] (p : ps) = itWilcard (p : ps)
qpFunc (s : os) (p : ps)
 | ...
```

It's unnecessary to use a `head : tail` pattern though, because you're anyway just passing the whole thing on to `itWildcard`. So just make it

```
qpFunc [] [] = ("", "")
qpFunc [] ps = itWilcard ps
qpFunc (s : os) (p : ps)
 | ...
```